# Implementation of "Context.getApplicationContext().getBean"

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

Can anyone explain what happens when we call

```
ApplicationContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(abcclassName.class)
```

being the abcclassName being an abstract class.

I understand that an abstract class cannot be instantiated. Then how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this with Abstract Classes, but with Interfaces.

What it will do is to get the instance of the subclass defined in your context. In other words if you have a bean of the class Cat (subclass of Animal) defined in your context and you use the class Animal to pass to your ApplicationContext.getBean(). You will get the Cat back.

If you have more than one subclass in your context, it will throw an exception though.

See this for reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean%28java.lang.Class%29

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source code for [DefaultListableBeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html) -- [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/3.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java) --  should answer your question.  (Both links are for version 3.0.x, as that is what I found with GrepCode.  I imagine that not much has changed in terms of finding the matching beans by a type)

Basically, it takes the class, and looks for Beans in the ApplicationContext that are assignable to the provided type.

The method `AbstractBeanFactory#isTypeMatch(String, Class<?>)` contains the code that will be of most interest to you, and there is a path that reaches it via the `DefulatListableBeanFactory#getBean(Class<?>)` method.

Answer (score 0):

After going through Source code Spring 3.0.5 , when you do 
`ApplicationContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(abcclassName.class)` on abstract class and if the abstract class is not configured as @component then the AbstractBeanFactory calls the isTypematch method to get the Correct Entity . 
 
Basically it takes all beans ( which ever initiated in context) and iterate one by one and will check that bean is factory for requested or the bean can be assignable for the requested.

  if only one bean resolved using that type then it returns that bean 
 
 if its found multiple beans then it returned error .

```
return !BeanFactoryUtils.isFactoryDereference(name) &&
                    typeToMatch.isAssignableFrom(beanInstance.getClass());
```

The `typeToMatch.isAssignableFrom(beanInstance.getClass());` call use Native method in Object class `public native boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls);` to check